# Stop on any error and return the Json response

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony, logic, php-5.5

I have this code and I'm asking which is the best way to stop code execution and go directly trough response if any fails. Take a look to this:

```
public function guardarPaso6Action(Request $request)
{
    $em                  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session             = $request->getSession();
    $response['success'] = false;
    $status              = null;

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $productoSolicitud = $session->get('productoSolicitudId');
        $productoSolicitudEntity = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:ProductoSolicitud")->find($productoSolicitud);

        if (! $productoSolicitud) {
            $status = 400;
            $response['error'] = $this->get('translator')->trans('mensajes.msgElementoNoEncontrado', array('%pronombre%' => 'la','%elemento%' => 'solicitud de producto'), 'AppBundle');
        }

        $fabricanteEntity = new Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor();
        $fabricanteForm = $this->createForm(new Form\FabricanteForm(), $fabricanteEntity);
        $fabricanteForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($fabricanteForm->isValid()) {
            try {
                $em->persist($fabricanteEntity);
                $em->flush();
                $session->set('fabricanteEntityId', $fabricanteEntity->getId());
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                $status = 400;
                $response['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
            }

            // Some code goes here

            $dataResponse['paises'] = $nombresPaises;
            $response['entities'] = $dataResponse;
            $response['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $status = 400;
            $response['error'] = $this->getFormErrors($fabricanteForm);
        }
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response, $status ?: 200);
}
```

In this case:

- If if `!$productoSolicitud` should stop code execution and goes through `JsonResponse`
- If any `catch (\Exception $ex)` should stop code execution and goes through `JsonResponse`

Did you get the big idea? Just stop code execution on error and goes through `return` statement. How I achieve this? I'm not sure if using `exit` or `break` will do the job but still in doubt for me, any advice around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the response when you want to stop the execution:

```
    public function guardarPaso6Action(Request $request)
    {
        $em                  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session             = $request->getSession();
        $response['success'] = false;
        $status              = 400;

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $productoSolicitud = $session->get('productoSolicitudId');
            $productoSolicitudEntity = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:ProductoSolicitud")->find($productoSolicitud);

            if (! $productoSolicitud) {
                $response['error'] = $this->get('translator')->trans('mensajes.msgElementoNoEncontrado', array('%pronombre%' => 'la','%elemento%' => 'solicitud de producto'), 'AppBundle');

                return new JsonResponse($response, $status);
            }

            $fabricanteEntity = new Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor();
            $fabricanteForm = $this->createForm(new Form\FabricanteForm(), $fabricanteEntity);
            $fabricanteForm->handleRequest($request);

            if ($fabricanteForm->isValid()) {
                try {
                    $em->persist($fabricanteEntity);
                    $em->flush();
                    $session->set('fabricanteEntityId', $fabricanteEntity->getId());
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    $response['error'] = $ex->getMessage();

                    return new JsonResponse($response, $status);
                }

                // Some code goes here

                $dataResponse['paises'] = $nombresPaises;
                $response['entities'] = $dataResponse;
                $response['success'] = true;
                $status = 200;
            } else {
                $response['error'] = $this->getFormErrors($fabricanteForm);
            }
        }

        return new JsonResponse($response, $status);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to throw exceptions instead of using if-else and suround everything with try-catch. 
Like this:

```
try
  {
   if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
   {
        $productoSolicitud = $session->get('productoSolicitudId');
        $productoSolicitudEntity = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:ProductoSolicitud")->find($productoSolicitud);

        if (! $productoSolicitud) throw new \Exception ( $this->get('translator')->trans('mensajes.msgElementoNoEncontrado', array('%pronombre%' => 'la','%elemento%' => 'solicitud de producto'), 'AppBundle') );

        $fabricanteEntity = new Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor();
        $fabricanteForm = $this->createForm(new Form\FabricanteForm(), $fabricanteEntity);
        $fabricanteForm->handleRequest($request);

        if (!$fabricanteForm->isValid())   throw new \Exception ( json_encode( $this->getFormErrors($fabricanteForm) ));

        $em->persist($fabricanteEntity);
        $em->flush();
        $session->set('fabricanteEntityId', $fabricanteEntity->getId());


        // Some code goes here

        $dataResponse['paises'] = $nombresPaises;
        $response['entities'] = $dataResponse;
        $response['success'] = true;
    }
  }
  catch (\Exception $ex)
  {
      $status = 400;
      $response['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
  }
  return new JsonResponse($response, $status ?: 200);
```

When using symfony controllers, you should never terminate the php script (like with exit) itself, but always end gracefully by returning a valid response so that any downstream components still get called.